# Get Id of clicked +1 google button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-plus

Helow everybody,

My problem is described on title there is the code:

```html
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="standard" data-callback="GplusClick" data-annotation="none" data-href="http://URL" id="ID"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function GplusClick(jsonParam){
  if(jsonParam.state=='on')
  {
 alert(ids);
  }
}
</script>
```

Fine I want just get the Id of g-plusone button.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your question is extremely vague, but if i understand you correctly, you just want to get the ID of the clicks Google Plus element.

Something like this should work:

```js
var GplusClick = function(element) {
  alert(element.id); 
}
```

```html
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="standard" data-annotation="none" data-href="http://URL" id="dynamicId" onclick="GplusClick(this)">+1</div>
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="standard" data-annotation="none" data-href="http://URL" id="anotherDynamicId" onclick="GplusClick(this)">+1</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but it's alert(undefined), it's relative to google+1 button ;)

Comment: run the code snippet above ^ it works just fine.  i added the "onclick" attribute

Comment: Yes I know that it's working but the problem is when we add the: <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery, this should do what you need

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="standard" data-callback="GplusClick" data-annotation="none" data-href="http://URL" id="ID"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.g-plusone').click(function(){
        alert(this.id);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not alerting anything :) it's relative to Google+1 button ;)